# Manipulating Legend in Pickled Matplotlib Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

Is it possible to manipulate a legend in a pickled matplotlib figure

Eg, I plot a figure and then pickle it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle as pkl

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]

fig = plt.figure('plot')
plt.plot(x,y, label = 'label')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')

pkl.dump(fig,file('plot.pkl','wb'))
```

I then load the pickled figure

```
fig = pkl.load(open('plot.pkl','rb'))
plt.show()
```

I now need to extract the figure labels to use in an interactive widget. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "peel" the figure:

```
labels = [label.get_text() for label in ax.legend().texts for ax in fig.axes]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the legend appearing on the plot?

Comment: Be more explicit. Which plot are you talking about ? If you don't want the legend why you use label ?

Comment: I'm extracting the label to use in an interactive widget (to turn on/off specific series) but don't actually want the legend on the plot. When I add `labels = [label.get_text() for label in ax.legend().texts for ax in fig.axes]` the legend automatically appears.

Comment: I dont really understand your process but try: **ax.legend_.texts** instead of ax.lengend().texts

Comment: Got it right with `plt.legend().set_visible(False)`. Thanks for your help!